# Custom Setting Access

Tags: permissions, customsetting

I have 2 public list custom settings. Both can be exposed via the Custom Setting UI and Apex with the Customize Application permission. However, without that permission 1 of the Custom Settings is visible and the other is not. I've granted the View All Custom Settings Permission and specifically included both of the in the Custom Settings Definitions on a Permission Set.

I can't rely on the Customize Application permission as this is a managed package and I know for a fact some customers won't grant it.

What might I be missing? I'm scratching my head a little here as to why one is available and the other isn't even though the definition for the two is both Public List.

Comment: After spring 20, you will have to add it under profile.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about "Visible"? What is the way that it is being checked?

Comment: @kurunve I mean that when I attempt to access it via Apex, it is not returned in the Schema.getGlobalDescribe() call, while another Custom Setting that is defined the same way is. If I try to reference it directly, i.e. CustomSetting__c.getAll(), I get an error that indicates it doesn't exist.

If I do the same with Customize Application, this is not the case.

Comment: @Ayub can you elaborate a little? I've added permissions to profiles to no avail. I also have a 2nd custom setting that is defined the same way which is not experiencing this problem.

Comment: @kurunve to expand on that, when I view the Custom Setting UI, neither has the Manage link in the list view but I can click a Manage button in the definition. For the problem custom setting, the 1 record is not displayed, while for the other setting, all 35 records are displayed. Further, for the problem setting, I get an insufficient privileges warning if I try to create a new list view but I can create a new list view for the one I can see the records for.

Since both are public list custom settings in the same managed package, I'm baffled by one behaving different than the other.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up filing a case with Salesforce that was escalated to tier 3 support as there we no permissions we were missing. Since that was taking too long and we had affected customers, we threw the old custom setting away and created a new one, which works just fine. So we still don't know what happened but it seems like the permissions for that custom setting ended up getting corrupted in our dev org and several subscriber orgs.